# WCF Error A SOAP 1.2 message is not valid when sent to a SOAP 1.1 only using wsHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, soap, x509certificate, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I am trying to consume a service which I have no control over and have been given just the WSDL to consume. The service requires a certificate for authentication. My configuration for the certificate is fine and I get an error when I try and call the service as below:

> The content type text/xml;charset=UTF-8 of the response message does
>   not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml;
>   charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the
>   IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 274
>   bytes of the response were: 'soap:VersionMismatchA SOAP 1.2 message is not valid when sent to a SOAP 1.1 only
>   endpoint.'.

I have tried different this  like using a customBinding but I landed up with a total new number of more errors and feel am not getting anyway. Can you please assist?

Client Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint name="IDeliveryServiceImplPort" 
                address="WebServiceUrl" 
                binding="wsHttpBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding"
                behaviorConfiguration="wsHttpCertificateBehavior"
                contract="IDeliveryService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="MyIdentity" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>

    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false"
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                 messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
                 useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas
            maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192"
            maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096"
            maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession enabled="false" ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="WsHttpSoap11"  closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" />
          <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" />
          <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="true" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="wsHttpCertificateBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="MyIdentity" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
            <serviceCertificate>
              <defaultCertificate x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="MyIdentity" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" />
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to figure it out with tweaks and trials. In order to solve is I change to basicHttpsBinding which took me another day or two to figure out the default transport clientCredentialType is None and you need to configure a custom binding as below. I wish WCF would tell you why or give a solution to error you get, because it was such a pain. From one error description to the next nonstop.

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpsBinding>
        <binding name="SecureHubBinding">
          <security>
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"  />
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are these configurations automatically generated by adding service reference? We can use the WSDL file of the service to generate the binding information used by the server-side and add the service reference to generate the client proxy class.
In addition, if the service with transport security mode authenticates the client with a certificate, please guarantee that below requirements.

1. The trusted relationship between the client-side and the server-side
   should be established. Install mutual certificates in the Local CA.
2. These two certificates should be accessed by the WCF application.
   Please add the Everyone account (or the account running the WCF
   application) to the management group of the certificate private key.
3. Both two certificates should have the client authentication intended
   purpose and the server authentication intended purpose.

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.